# Selective.js não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema com o meu código. Não consigo executar o *plugin* selectize.js nessa página. Todos os caminhos estão corretos. O *input* aparece e tudo mais, no entanto, quando clico para digitar, o plugin não mostra a lista de opções e acabando não listando nada dos meus `options`. O que poderia ser?

Quando jogo no navegador, aparece os seguintes erros no DOM:

> teste-form.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined //
>   $('#select-country').selectize();

// Código da index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Selectize.js Demo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectize/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectize/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="js/selectize/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/selectize/selectize.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectize/selectizedefault.css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="control-group">

            <label for="select-country">Country:</label>
            <select id="select-country" class="demo-default selectized" placeholder="Select a country..." tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            </select>

            <div class="selectize-control demo-default single">
                <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="Select a country..." style="width: 111px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
                </div>

                <div class="selectize-dropdown demo-default single" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 1703px; top: 36px; left: 0px;">

                    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
                        <div data-value="AF" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            Afghanistan
                        </div>
                        <div data-value="AX" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            Åland Islands
                        </div>
                        <div data-value="AL" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            Albania
                        </div>
                        <div data-value="DZ" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            Algeria
                        </div>
                        <div data-value="AS" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            American Samoa
                        </div>
                        <div data-value="AD" data-selectable="" class="option">
                            Andorra
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            $(function(){
            $('input').selectize({
            delimiter: ',',
            persist: false,
            create: function(input) {
              return {
                value: input,
                text: input
              }
            }
            });
            });

            $('#select-country').selectize();

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a descrição no GitHub do *plugin*:

> Selectize is the hybrid of a textbox and  box. **It's jQuery based** and it has autocomplete and native-feeling keyboard navigation; useful for tagging, contact lists, etc.

Ele possui algumas dependências. É necessário a importação do [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) antes de realizar uma chamada ao *selectize.js*.

<kbd>[**DOCUMENTAÇÃO**](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)</kbd>

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
      return {
        value: input,
        text: input
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/css/selectize.css'/>

<input type='text' placeholder='Digite algo e pressione "enter" ou ","...'/>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/js/standalone/selectize.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Renan, estou com o mesmo comportamento ainda... Não esta aparecendo a lista e nem buscando nada.

Comment: Poderia entrar no skype? A lista que eu digo, são os valores de "option", como eu coloquei lá em cima...

Comment: Renan, qual seria o code para o option então?

Comment: @user11873 Não sei, não entendi nada naquele código. O problema não era o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`?

Comment: Então, posso te mostrar como está o code? Poderia entrar no skype? me add ai: ferreira.studios

Comment: Pronto já add o código.